# What is the difference between "selectRootElement" and "createViewRoot"

Tags: javascript, angular

in the "Renderer" section, the official documentation does not specify... "Not Yet Documented" [url](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectRootElement` selects root element from DOM:

```
selectRootElement(selector: string): Element {...}
```

while `createViewRoot` creates ShadowDOM root at `hostElement`:

```
createViewRoot(hostElement: any): any {...}
```

You can see difference in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e7470d557df0400a812d84551524970cb5f12eee/modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L83-L121).

Comment: Ok thanks but, what is the meaning of "ShadowDOM root"?

Comment: It's the root of the [ShadowDOM tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#shadow-trees).